# Has anyone built Freeradius on ARM?

Tags: arm, freeradius

I was hoping to run Freeradius on ARM but have not found a build yet.    I am setting up an environment for cross-compiling but wanted to have one last check before I go down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's even bundled with OpenWRT.  We have an ARM 1U server that we're hoping to start ARM build packages on soon and release them in some kind of official way.

Comment: OK. So I won't find it on the Freeradius site yet.  Correct?

Comment: Why the downvote?  I see builds by OS but not by architecture.  It is fairly well assumed most of those builds are x64.

Comment: Downvote wasn't me... but, these days, there shouldn't be that many portability issues. FreeRADIUS 3 is C99 FreeRADIUS 4 (unreleased) is C11, we don't use inline assembly, or any fun stuff like longjmp, and unaligned memory access has been supported since ARM7, so unless you're running on older ARM systems, that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: and no, not available yet.

Comment: Thank you!   Good to know about the compilation.  The endianness should be the same (little) as x64.